# Java and traversing loop

Tags: java, arrays, traversal

This question is somewhat related to my earlier post about how to traverse multi-dimensional arrays.

EDIT: I've added three images of how I would like the cube to be rearranged. The first image shows a 2x2x2 cube with numbers set in their default positions. The second image shows the same cube with the first column rotated counterclockwise. The third image shows the Z, X and Y axes.

[image: Default cube with the default setup of integers]
[image: The rearranged values of the Y column at position 0]
[image: Cube's Z, X and Y values are displayed]

EDIT 2: I've changed the values.
EDIT 1: Based on what I could estimate with pen and paper, I have the following loop iterations. In this case it will be the numbers 0, 2, 4 and 6 in the cube above. These are the Z, X and Y values from where the numbers should be taken:

```
z  x  y
0  0  0
0  1  0
1  0  0
1  1  0
```

EDIT 2: I've changed the values and replaced old z with zz and old x with xx. This was needed as one side (container) had to use the z value while the other (containerTemp) needed the zz value (the z value in reverse).
EDIT 1: The numbers 0, 2, 4 and 6 should be placed in the following locations just as they are taken from the locations mentioned above:

```
zz xx  y
 1  0  0
 0  0  0
 1  1  0
 0  1  0
```

EDIT 2: It means that the value 0 at position 0 0 0 (z x y) will be moved to the location of value 4 at position 1 0 0 (zz xx y).

Note: I understand that this is not normally how the Z, X and Y positions are used in a 3D matrix and perhaps that is why find it harder to solve this. I have the rotations and flips completed for each slice of the cube so I do not feel like I should change the way the code works as of this moment (of course I'm open for WOW recommendations, if I think like a moron). I just wanted to become better at matrix manipulations as I never sit with this kind of stuff even in my career.

SOLVED: I used the following code for my project. The code will however not work for 2x3x2 groupings. So I guess this solution should only be used for equal sized cubes. I will look into it but it is not required for my project as of this moment. If someone feels like know a better way please tell me as I want to learn more!

```
for (int y = 0; y < yDim; y++) {
    for (int z = 0; z < zDim; z++) {
        for (int x = 0, zz = xDim - 1, xx = z; x < xDim; x++, zz--) {
            System.out.println("["+zz+"]["+xx+"]["+y+"] = ["+z+"]["+x+"]["+y+"]");
            containerTemp[zz][xx][y] = container[z][x][y];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe it's just my lack of understanding, but i don't quite get the question. Do you have the first array and u want using code to get the second one? or didn't i get at all?

Comment: @Or251 : I want all values to be rearranged while traversing the arrays. Imagine you look into one of the sides of a Rubik's cube and you turn one side/column 90 degrees clockwise/counterclockwise. I have the code for turning values clockwise/counterclockwise for a normal X by Y grid but not when I add the Z axis into the mix. Imagine the values on the cube to be written on the side you are facing, the values should be rearranged in the same order as you see them move while you turn.

Comment: If I was implementing something like this, i think, if i get it right, that you can have 6 2 dimensional arrays, which representing the rubik's cube, and you can manipulate this 6 cube faces instead of implementing the 3rd dimension. It's just a suggestion, but to me it's look easier. If you are having hard time implementing the way i suggested, lemme know :)

Comment: @Or251 : I rather not start all over when I got the turning and flipping to work of the X by Y grids (clockwise/counterclockwise). This column thing is not required, I just wanted to see if I could make it work as I did with the X and Y rotations.

Also, I do not get what you mean with 6 2d arrays. How that would make it easier...

Answer (score 0):

Think about like that - every time you turn a Rubik's cube, you turn **one slice** of the cube which is actually a **two-dimensional array** which you know how to solve.

So each turn you need to:

1. Realize *what is* the right two-dimensional array you need (I guess it will be given using a fixed value of `x`, `y` or `z`, for example - `y=2` will define a two-dimensional array of `x`on`z` where all the `y` values are `2`)
2. Apply on it the algorithm you have already
3. Copy the results to the original three-dimensional array.

So for the case of `y=2` it will be something like (pseudo code):

```
// defining the two-dimensional array (the "slice") from the cube-array
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        arr[i,k] = origArr[i,2,k]
    }
}

// turning the two-dimensional array with the function we already have
turnedArr = turn(arr)

// copying the resulted two-dimensional array back to the cube
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        origArr[i,2,k] = turnedArr[i,k]
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll have to pay attention to where you start the iteration for every axis's index and if you're increasing or decreasing etc, but that's the main idea.